# On using "agree on it more"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

Is this a correct sentence?

> A nice statement that we can not agree on it more.

I used to use: Can't agree more. But the above use is new to me.

Comment: Not sure what that statement is intended to mean; it's not colloquial English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sentence would be made up of a main clause and a that-clause, but there is no verb in "A nice statement": the whole thing is not a sentence but a noun phrase.

In a that-clause, the relative pronoun **that** represents within the that-clause the thing that was mentioned in the main clause: it already does the job that **it** is doing, so **it** is not required.

The stock phrase "I can't agree more" is widely used in conversation, and means that you agree completely with what the other person said. It sounds wrong if you add **on** to it because, if you can't agree on something, it means that you disagree.

It would be better to replace the stock phrase with phrasing that does not contain negatives. If you want a sentence rather than a noun phrase, add "this is" at the beginning:

> This is a nice statement that we can all agree on wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 0):

There's an idiom in English, "I couldn't agree with you more." But you have to be careful with idioms. Often even a small variation and it ceases to sound natural or even make sense.

The sentence you give is close, but not quite the "standard wording". Well, as @JavaLatte points out, it's not a complete sentence. But even if you made it a grammatically correct sentence, like, "That's a nice statement that I couldn't agree with more", it sounds awkward because you're twisting the idiom.